# Simple selection from finite list

Tags: c++

I have three variables that need to be set in a certain way.  For example,

```
int a, b, c;
a = choose(1, 2,  3);   // a can take the value 1 to 3 inclusive
b = choose(1, 2,  3);   // b can take the value 1 to 3 inclusive
c = ??????              // c can't take either of the values in a or b.
```

The easiest way I can think of for setting c is to use a loop:

```
do
{
    c = choose(1, 2,  3);
}
while(c == a || c == b);
```

Alternatively I could use ifs or a switch, or a switch/if combo:

```
a = choose(1, 2,  3);   
b = choose(1, 2,  3);   

switch(a){
    case 1:
        switch(b){
            case 1:
                c = choose(2, 3)
                break;
            case 2:
                c = 3;
                break;
            case 3:
                c = 2;
                break;
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        …
```

Neither of these seems elegant, and the latter is just bloody ugly.

I had another similar situation in a project where I've used `std::set` and `set_difference`, but I can't use that here, and have to use a rather less STL like and more old school C++ solution.

Any ideas please?

Comment: I found the first one elegant.

Comment: Add optional values to `choose` that removes those from use? `c = choose(1, 2, 3, a, b);`

Comment: So `choose` takes a fixed number of elements?

Comment: @jerry @crashmstr the choose() function doesn't actually exist at this point, but if it did, it would probably just be: `return rand() % 3 + 1;`.

I could write choose as a variadic, but as it's not able to be passed anything smart like a `std::list` but could only work on an array, it doesn't seem that it would help?

Comment: @peedurrr I think a variadic function is overkill. Note that most answers assume the presence of `choose` that can different number of inputs, though maybe still fixed. This could be acheived with overloading or passing in an array and its size, but given the simple nature of your proposed implementation, you could just as easily call `rand` directly. Speaking of which, `rand() % 3`, is less than ideal (especially since it sounds like you're operating in a constrained environment), though it may be adequate for your situation.

Comment: @jerry - yes, I agree that overloading would be better than a variadic.  Also, it's fine to assume that choose() actually exists - I have no problem doing it that way. Lastly, `rand() % 3` being less than ideal, can you explain please?

Comment: @peedurrr Many implementations of `rand` are of relatively low quality. They are often even worse when only looking at the low order bits, which will result from applying `%` to the result with a divisor that is a power of `2` (like you might do for a two input overload), though `3` is okay. Even assuming you have a perfectly random `rand`, since your divisor (almost certainly) does not evenly divide the range, you've introduced a (very slight) bias. As I said, it may be perfectly fine for what you want to do, but I thought you should know.

Comment: @jerry, that's really very interesting, thank you. Any pointer as to a better approach at all please?

Comment: @peedurr It's a complicated subject, more so than I can claim to understand. It really does depend on your quality needs and your platform. Again, `rand` may suit your purpose fine and is simple. Otherwise you could try `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom` on Linux and `CryptGenRandom` on Windows. `boost::random` is another alternative, though you still have to worry about seeding. A flaw in any of these is likely to be well below the threshold you care about, but it comes with cost in terms of execution time and memory usage (not to mention learning curve to get it working correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

On second look, it makes more sense to **pick the unique element first**, followed by the other two. It's cleaner this way, though maybe still not elegant.

If you stick with the discrete variable implementation of `choose`, it might look something like this:

```
int choose(int, int); // two choice overload
int choose(int, int, int); // three choice overload

int main()
{
    int c = choose(1, 2, 3);

    int x = 1 + c % 3;
    int y = 1 + (c + 1) % 3;

    int a = choose(x, y);
    int b = choose(x, y);
}
```

Using an array is even cleaner and can be made a little more general with little effort:

```
int choose(int[], int); // takes an array and its (effective) size

int main()
{
    constexpr int maxNum = 3;

    int choices[maxNum] = {1, 2, 3};

    //for larger values of maxNum, loop initialize:
    //for(int i = 0; i < maxNum; i++)
    //{
    //    choices[i] = i + 1;
    //}

    int c = choose(choices, maxNum);

    choices[c-1] = maxNum;

    int a = choose(choices, maxNum - 1);
    int b = choose(choices, maxNum - 1);
}
```

---

For only three variables, I would take the simplest approach and use the `while` loop you posted:

```
do
{
    c = choose(1, 2,  3);
}
while(c == a || c == b);
```

If you really need that guarantee of deterministic run-time, you could try something like the following. However, I'm not sure everyone would find it more "elegant" and I don't think the maintainability hit is worth it.

```
if(a != b)
{
    c = 6 - (a + b);
}
else
{
    c = choose(0, 1);

    c = 1 + (a + c) % 3;
}
```

Neither is all that scalable given how the question is set up, but until a need to make it more general arises, I'd assume [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).

Comment: I actually really liked the last one.  The edit won't work for me as I really have to pick c last.

Comment: @peedurrr I see. Two more questions, if that's okay. 1) What's the actual use can (i.e., why must `c` actually be picked last)? 2) Any chance you'll have to change/scale it (e.g., by increasing the number of variables, widening the range, or making the choices non-consecutive)?

Comment: Last bit first, no, it doesn't need to scale - it will always be 1, 2, 3. The actual use is in a game simulation (game theory, rather than Xbox etc) - we have a certain scenario (in real life) that we want to model.  We want to keep the actual steps (in code) aligned with those taken in the real life situation; in which c is always chosen after a and b have been selected jerry.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider this, as an improvement (elegance-wise) of your second solution:

```
switch ((1<<a)|(1<<b))
{
    case  2: // a,b == 1,1
        c = choose(2,3);
        break;
    case  4: // a,b == 2,2
        c = choose(1,3);
        break;
    case  6: // a,b == 1,2 or 2,1
        c = 3;
        break;
    case  8: // a,b == 3,3
        c = choose(1,2);
        break;
    case 10: // a,b == 1,3 or 3,1
        c = 2;
        break;
    case 12: // a,b == 2,3 or 3,2
        c = 1;
        break;
}
```

You can further improve it by mapping two values to choose from, for each value of `(1<<a)|(1<<b)`:

```
static int first[]  = {2,1,3,1,2,1};
static int second[] = {3,3,3,2,2,1};
int index = ((1<<a)|(1<<b))/2-1; // reduce from [2,4,6,8,10,12] to [0,1,2,3,4,5]
c = choose(first[index],second[index]);
```

And there you have an elegant solution without `switch`, `while` or any other conditional statement...

Comment: I like both suggestions, and although they do have elegance, they perhaps lack readability.  Curious to know how you thought of this solution - I don't know that it would ever have occurred to me.

Comment: @peedurrr: I believe that the first suggestion is readable enough (due to the comments of course). It occurred to me, as I often have the situation of nested `switch` statements, and this is just a simple scheme for "flattening" them into a single `switch` statement. I derived the second suggestion directly from the first suggestion (as explained in the answer itself). I agree that this suggestion is less readable though...

Answer (score 1):

Do you really just have 3 values like this or is this a minimized example?
For this case I'd straight-forward exclude taken values

```
int a, b, c;
a = choose(1, 2,  3);   // a can take the value 1 to 3 inclusive
b = choose(1, 2,  3);   // b can take the value 1 to 3 inclusive
c = 1;
if(a == c || b == c)
  c = 2;
if(a == c || b == c)
  c = 3;
```

If the values are 1,2,3 you could replace that with a while loop that does `c++` similar to yours:

```
c = 1;
while(a == c || b == c)
    c++;
```

If `c` needs to be `chosen` the while loop you presented seems fine to me.

Comment: While you may be right, I understood the question to mean that `c` should still take on all values with equal probability. Obviously these solutions favor lower numbers.

Comment: I like it - very simple.  @jerry, good point, but I think that could be fixed by initially setting `c = choose(1, 2, 3);`

Comment: @peedurrr yes, though you need to add a little complexity back to make sure it wraps correctly.

Comment: @jerry, please explain the 'wrap' comment.

Comment: @peedurrr If you set `c = choose(1, 2, 3);` and try to increment it `while(a == c || b == c)` to get a unique value, it may end up being `4`. You have to wrap that back to `1` to keep it in your desired range.

Comment: @jerry - duh, good point. I think I'm loosing it! So, instead of c++ I need something like `c = c == 3 ? choose(1, 2) : ++c;` not as pretty.

Comment: For those cases I'd highly prefer the OP's original while loop.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to pass a linked list (by reference) into the `choose` function.  An element that is chosen would be removed from the list and returned.  Subsequent calls to the function would have fewer and fewer elements to choose from.

You would have to take note of when the list is empty and handle it accordingly.

If `a` and `b` are allowed to be the same, then `choose` would not be the function you are using for determining `c`.  In that case, have a separate function `chooseC` that takes a list of chosen values (by constant reference) and a list of available values (by value).  Remove the chosen values from the available values, and pick from what is left.

Comment: Even assuming `choose` can be modified like this, it doesn't seem like this is quite what the OP is looking for. Based on the question, `a` and `b` may both have the same value, so whatever was chosen for `a` should not be removed from the list. However, I think removing elements is the right idea, especially if it's going to be scaled.

Comment: @jerry I was just thinking about that.  I was under the presumption that `choose` would make them all unique, but that may or may not be what he is asking.

Comment: I based my interpretation on the comments `// a can take the value 1 to 3 inclusive` and `// b can take the value 1 to 3 inclusive` as well as the fact that the nested `switch` statement has a case where `a == 1 && b == 1` (and so `c = choose(2, 3)`).

Comment: @jerry Agreed.  I've added a section describing how to handle that case as well.

Comment: `choose()` is a theoretical function at this point. I agree that if it could be passed a `std::list` or some such, that removing items would be good. However, it can only be passed intrinsic types. That could of course include a linked-list, but that seems overly complicated. The more I think about it, and read the replies here, I'm starting to think that the `do` loop is the clearest, most readable, if not the most optimal solution at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
int a, b, c;
int myList[]= {1, 2, 3};

a = choose(myList);   // if choose can take a list as input
b = choose(myList);

myList.remove(a);
myList.remove(b);

c = choose(myList);  // the selection from a and b are out of the list at this point
```

This solution ensures that

```
a != b && a != c
```

Comment: Arrays don't have a `remove` method. Also, the `choose` function didn't seem to take an array in the question.

Comment: @jerry I wasn't sure what container he had (1, 2, 3) in to pass into Choose. Unless Choose just takes exactly 3 inputs individually. It may take an array rather than a std::list in which case this solution won't do the trick for them

Comment: I took "I can't use that here, and have to use a rather less STL like and more old school C++ solution" to mean "no `std` containers". `choose` takes individual `int`s in the question and there's nothing to indicate it's different in the OP's actual code, so that's what I'd assume.